# Vue Multiselect does not update {{ value }} via v-model

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5.3, vuejs2

I am using this example for Vue Multiselect "^2.0.0-beta.14" in Laravel 5.3. https://github.com/monterail/vue-multiselect/tree/2.0#install--basic-usage

The plugin renders correctly but I cannot get the selection via v-model. I am expecting `@{{ selected }}` to update with the current selection.

**app.js**

```
Vue.component('dropdown', require('./components/Multiselect.vue'));
```

**VUE JS**

```
<template>
 <div>
   <multiselect
     v-model="value"
     :options="options">
   </multiselect>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
  import Multiselect from 'vue-multiselect'
  export default {
    components: { Multiselect },
    data () {
      return {
        value: null,
        options: ['list', 'of', 'options']
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<style src="vue-multiselect/dist/vue-multiselect.min.css"></style>
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="app">
  <h3>Dropdown</h3>
  <div>
    <label class="typo__label">Single select</label>
    <dropdown></dropdown>
    <pre class="language-json"><code>@{{ value  }}</code></pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

**NB**
The official example uses **selected** instead of value but this does not work either. According to the docs selection is replaced by value as of V2.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The reason value is not showing up in root is because the data is isolated to the dropdown component. To get your data from a component to show up in the Root you need to use props.

See this question for a detailed explanation

[How to get data from a component in VueJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42684754/how-to-get-data-from-a-component-in-vuejs)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using TypeScript Interfaces with Vue.js 2.0, avoid using a optional properties to store the value from child components.  i.e. if your property is
`value:? IMyCustomInterface` instead use `value: MyCustomObject|null` and set the object to null in the constructor.

If the property is optional, it will compile fine, but child components won't update it properly.