# Update data in Root from Component in Vue JS

Tags: components, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a Vue component and I want to update a data source in the Root. I am already doing this with props but I am having trouble adding a second source called `titleActive` to it, the value of `titleActive` does not update on the root.

**Component JS**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <label v-for="topic in topics" class="radio-inline radio-thumbnail">
      <input type="radio" @click="selectedValue(topic)" name="topics_radio" :id="topic.id" :value="topic.name" :checked="value && topic.id == value.id">
      <span class="white-color lg-text font-regular text-center text-capitalize">{{ topic.name }}</span>
    </label>
    <ul class="hidden">
      <li>{{ value }}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: ['value','titleActive'],
    data () {
      return {
        topics: [],
        titleActive: false
      }
    },
    methods:{
      selectedValue(topic){
        this.$emit('input', topic);
        this.titleActive = true;
      }
    },
    mounted(){
      axios.get('/vuetopics').then(response => this.topics = response.data);
    }
  }
</script>
```

**Vue Instance**

```
<script>
    var App = new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data: {
              selectedTopic: null,
              selectedKeywords: null,
              selectedProfiles: null,
              questionTitle: null,
              titleActive: false
            },
            methods: {
              titleBlur: function(){
                // this.selectedTopic = null;
              }

            }
        });
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group" id="app">
    <topic v-model="selectedTopic"></topic>
</div>
```

Comment: What is titleActive supposed to indicate? Could you not just watch changes to selectedTopic and set it appropriately in the Vue?

Comment: Hi, that would be ideal but I am using it to move a highlight class between steps on a form. So unfortunately I need something else besides selectedTopic for it to work. For instance I can set the highlight class on step 1 with `v-bind:class="{ 'highlight': !selectedTopic }"` and then step 2 with `v-bind:class="{ 'highlight': selectedTopic }"` but then how do I remove the highlight class from step 2 when I go to step 3 without enabling it again for step 1?

Comment: I think I've found a better way using computed properties.

Comment: Sounds good. This (highlighting active form elements/steps) sounds like something that should be controlled outside the component.

Comment: Yeah I didn't even need computed properties in the end, I just used `vbind:class="{ highlight: statment1 && statement2 }"` By having more than one data source to compare I was able to work out which element should have the `.highlight` class on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was going about this the wrong way. So for anyone else who is dealing with elements that you need to switch a class between eg a form with 3 steps you can use the following method.

1. Step 1 uses a component and I get that data to the root using this
   question,
   [How to get data from a component in VueJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42684754/how-to-get-data-from-a-component-in-vuejs). The data received is called `selectedTopic`
2. Step 2 is a static input, the data is called questionTitle, obtained
       via v-model
3. Step 3 is a static textarea, the data is called questionDescription,
       obtained via v-model

Now we need a way to cycle the highlight class, luckily you can just use Vues v-bind:class feature. You just need to compare more than one value to work out which one should have the class.

1. So Step 1 will have `v-bind:class="{ highlight: !selectedTopic &&
   !questionTitle }"`
2. Step 2 will have `v-bind:class="{ highlight:
       selectedTopic && !questionTitle }"`
3. And Step 3 will have
       `v-bind:class="{ highlight: questionTitle && !questionDescription
       }"`

Using this method of getting a true statement by checking which values are loaded yet will help in situations like these.